# systemd: switch between targets without restarting services from third target

Tags: linux, systemd

i have two custom targets `A` and `B`:

`A.target`:

```
Description=A
Requires=multi-user.target
Wants=
Conflicts=B.target
After=multi-user.target
AllowIsolate=yes
```

`B.target`:

```
Description=B
Requires=multi-user.target
Wants=
Conflicts=A.target
After=multi-user.target
AllowIsolate=yes
```

If `A` is isolated, services in `A` are started, services in `B` are stopped and the other way round. That's good so far.

Problem:
Whenever i switch from `A` to `B` or `B` to `A`, all services in `multi-user.target` are restarted.

How can i prevent this?

Comment: Why are you requiring multi-user.target or trying to start after it? This is basically something you should never do.

Comment: because there are some basic services, that are enabled in both scenarios. They are currently in multi-user.target. Why should i never do this?

Comment: I suspect you have your logic backward. Services should be _required by_ (or more likely _wanted by_) multi-user.target. You have specified the reverse. For an example, look at pretty much every other service on your system.

Comment: @MichaelHampton you're right